# Unique hash with jQuery that can be reproduced in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, equivalence

I am using a script in wich I need to create a **unique** Hash with jQuery that I would be able similar to the PHP function `uniqid()`.

Any help ?

Comment: what do you mean "reproduce"? if you can reproduce it, it's not unique. you mean you want something in a similar format?

Comment: downvote: What have you tried? Google for `javascript random generator` and enjoy

Comment: Are you talking about the location.hash, which you don't have access to on the serverside? You're probably talking about password hashing, and the point of hashing is that it can't be reproduced, so what you need is some sort of encryption wich will work in both languages, and nothing like that is readily available, but there are plugins and more advanced solutions that will do that.

Comment: The point of hashing is that it CAN be reproduced...... if you have the same input. And md5 / sha / others, take your pick.

Comment: If you are about javascript uuid generation, try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/105074/2124762

Comment: Thanks mailk, i want to reproduce uniqId

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I think you need is the jquery md5 plugin that will create an md5 hash of a string which should shell out a unique hash for any string you give it. check out https://github.com/placemarker/jQuery-MD5

and then check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php for the php function to do the same

Answer (score 1):

[The uniqid function in php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) is using the current time in milliseconds. It is not possible to generate the same hash on the client, as timing will be different.